# JSON Response returning Full page HTML instead of JSON String

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using AJAX to get data in JSON format. My code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'Dashboard.aspx/GetOfficesByDept',
    data: "{ 'Dept': '" + deptcode + "','SelectedDate':'" + dateselected + "'}",
    success:function(response) {
            // do stuff
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

And vb code is :

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function GetOfficesByDept(ByVal Dept As String, ByVal SelectedDate As String) As List(Of Data)

        Dim MyInterface As fwInterface.fwInterface.fwInterface
        Dim MyImplementer As New fwBLL.SelfUpdates
        Dim MyCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim MyTable As New DataTable

        MyInterface = MyImplementer
        MyCommand.Parameters.Clear()


        Dim dataList As New List(Of Data)()

        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "GetOfficesByDeptAndEntryDate")
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptid", Dept)
        MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", UpToDate)

        Dim dtOffices As New DataTable()
        dtOffices = MyInterface.SelectAll(MyCommand)


        Dim colName As String = "Offices Count"
        Dim val As Integer = 0


        If dtOffices.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            val = dtOffices.Rows.Count
        End If
        dataList.Add(New Data(colName, val))
        Return dataList
    End Function
```

When i checked JSON response on fiddler, it is returning full page HTML instead of JSON Response. Is there something wrong in my code?

It is working fine on my local system(returns valid JSON response on Local Only) but not on live server.

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of this:
success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response.d);
                } ?

Comment: Is the response an error message?